# How to control the width of equations?

Tags: equations, subequations, column-width

I have a long width of equations.
Could I get the ideas to control the equations for matching the width?

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
    \footnotesize{\varepsilon(L) = \sum_{ij} \eta_i_j ||L(\vec{x_i} - \vec{x_j})||^2 \ + c \sum_{ijl} \eta_i_j (1-y_i_l) h[1+||L(\vec{x_i} - \vec{x_j})||^2 - ||L(\vec{x_i} - \vec{x_l})||^2]},
\end{equation}
```

Comment: By default, displayed math mode has no automatic line-breaking functionality. Traditional solution is to use multi-line displayed math environment from `amsmath` package and manually handle line-breaking and alignment. On the other hand, each of packages `breqn` and `nath` provides some sort of automatic line-breaking for displayed equations.

Comment: And, [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: (1l footnotesize does not take an argument (2) text font size commands should not be used in math mode (as you can see in the log where you've gotten a warning (3) you need to break the formula into lines, look at every math book, none are scaling formulas! Look up the align environment or the split environment. (4) you're using the wrong syntax for a norm. The proper syntax is `\lVert... `\rVert` not `||... ||` which is wrong in so many ways